# How Do I Get A Generated Id Back With OJDBC?

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to get the auto-generated id after an insert with ojdbc.

My code is like this:

```
public void insert(Connection con) throws SQLException {
    String query = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (ID, FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4, FIELD5, FIELD6, FIELD7, FIELD8) VALUES (SEQ_MY_TABLE_ID.NEXTVAL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    try {
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(query, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        stmt.setBigDecimal(1, null == field1 ? null : new BigDecimal(field1));
        stmt.setBigDecimal(2, null == field2 ? null : new BigDecimal(field2));
        stmt.setBigDecimal(3, field3);
        stmt.setString(4, field4);
        stmt.setBigDecimal(5, field5);
        stmt.setBigDecimal(6, null == field6 ? null : new BigDecimal(field6));
        stmt.setBigDecimal(7, null == field7 ? null : new BigDecimal(field7));
        stmt.setString(8, field8);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        ResultSet idResults = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        if(null != idResults && idResults.next()){
            id = null == idResults.getBigDecimal(ID_COLUMN_NAME) ? null : idResults .getBigDecimal(ID_COLUMN_NAME).toBigInteger();
            //do something with the id we get back from the database 
        }
    } finally {
        cleanupConnection(con, stmt, null);
    }
}
```

I am getting a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException: 8

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your PreparedStatement as below. I think you need to list all columns in an array and pass it as an argument to the prepareStatement. That might fix the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.

```
stmt = con.prepareStatement(query, new String[] {"ID","FIELD1","FIELD2","FIELD3","FIELD4","FIELD5","FIELD6","FIELD7","FIELD8"});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Option. `stmt = con.prepareStatement(query, String[]{ID_COLUMN_NAME});`

2) Option
Should work but i haven't tested it.
getReturnResultSet() - Returns result set that contains data returned from DML Returning.

```
public void insert(Connection con) throws SQLException {
    String query = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (ID, FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4, FIELD5, FIELD6, FIELD7, FIELD8) VALUES (SEQ_MY_TABLE_ID.NEXTVAL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) returning ID into ?     ";
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    try {
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setBigDecimal(1, null == field1 ? null : new BigDecimal(field1));
        stmt.setBigDecimal(2, null == field2 ? null : new BigDecimal(field2));
        stmt.setBigDecimal(3, field3);
        stmt.setString(4, field4);
        stmt.setBigDecimal(5, field5);
        stmt.setBigDecimal(6, null == field6 ? null : new BigDecimal(field6));
        stmt.setBigDecimal(7, null == field7 ? null : new BigDecimal(field7));
        stmt.setString(8, field8);
        stmt.registerReturnParameter(9, OracleTypes.INTEGER);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        ResultSet idResults = ((OraclePreparedStatement stmt).getReturnResultSet();
        if(null != idResults && idResults.next()){
            id = idResults.getInt(9);
        }
    } finally {
        cleanupConnection(con, stmt, null);
    }
}
```